# Specify webcam with sourceId in getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, getusermedia

I have two webcams and am trying to specify which one to show in my video tag. My HTML is simply `<video autoplay></video>`. Here is my javascript:

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

var constraints = {
    video: {
        optional: [{
            sourceId: "64-character-alphanumeric-source-id-here"
        }]
    }
};
var video = document.querySelector("video");

function successCallback(stream) {
    window.stream = stream; // stream available to console
    if (window.URL) {
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    } else {
        video.src = stream;
    }
    video.play();
}

function errorCallback(error) {
    console.log("navigator.getUserMedia error: ", error);
}

navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, successCallback, errorCallback);
```

However, even when I change the sourceId to my second webcam, I can't get it to display that webcam. [js.fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/7qaDS/)

Answer (score 1):

this code is working for me in mobile chrome: It tries to detect the back facing video stream.

```
MediaStreamTrack.getSources(function(sourceInfos) {
              var videoSourceId;
              for (var i = 0; i != sourceInfos.length; ++i) {
                var sourceInfo = sourceInfos[i];
                if(sourceInfo.kind == "video" && sourceInfo.facing == "environment") {
                  videoSourceId = sourceInfo.id;
                }
              }
              var constraints = {
                audio: false,
                video: {
                  optional: [{sourceId: videoSourceId}]
                }
              };
            ....
});
```

note that there is no fallback in this code

Comment: I don't need fallback as it is just running on one local computer that I will maintain. However, I have two USB webcams attached to a desktop computer, so there's not necessary an "environment" and "user" camera.

Comment: @MrPeanut Did you figured it out ?

Comment: @Kumar No I did not, but the project was postponed so I stopped working on it.

Comment: @MrPeanut Okay.